# Center multiple divs in a parent fiv and scale them

Tags: html, css

I have a problem. I have one parent div .wrap and 4 child divs .circle. (PUG HTML Preprocessor)

```
.wrap
  .circle
  .circle
  .circle
  .circle
```

I want to make a simple white background. And **.circle** divs into circles horizontally aligned inside **.wrap**.

this is my css:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.wrap{
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 500px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: 500ms;
}

.circle{
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(50%, -50%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: 300ms;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.circle:nth-child(1){
    left: 25%;
}

.circle:nth-child(2){
    left: 50%;
}

.circle:nth-child(3){
    left: 75%;
}

.circle:nth-child(4){
    left: 0%;
}
```

How can I center everything perfectly vertical? It always goes a but to left. 
And When I apply

```
transform: scale(1.1,1.1);
```

my circles move down.

[My code on CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/MareGraphics/pen/OBYeKr?editors=1100)

Comment: I am not sure I understand the look want to achieve, but you can align the circles such that the left margin is the same as the right margin by setting `.circle { /*...*/     transform: translate(75%, -50%); /*...*/ }`

Comment: It worked. Are You willing to explain why did it work so perfectly?
Well This is what I wanted. And when I add scale to this circles move down and scale, instead scaling in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the circles are centred with flexbox and remain that way even when scaled.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.wrap {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 500ms;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 300ms;
  background-color: lightblue;
  transform-origin: center center;
}

.circle:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/k-sav/pen/OBeJGa)

Comment: Oh, Thank You so much.
I will look into Flexbox, it's still new to me.